# How to return array list the data of one table in java?

Tags: java, list

I want to return arraylist of one table data out without using Bean/Transfer objects

```
ArrayList<MyBean> list = new ArrayList<myBean>();
```

not like above, because I dont have such MyBean Class in my application, but still i need to add each row of employee table to ArrayList

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance looking for `Arrays.asList()`, javadoc [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)).

> **Returns a fixed-size list backed by
>   the specified array.** (Changes to the
>   returned list "write through" to the
>   array.) This method acts as bridge
>   between array-based and
>   collection-based APIs, in combination
>   with Collection.toArray. The returned
>   list is serializable and implements
>   RandomAccess.

Comment: actually i want to transfer all enployees data from Employee table to flex Data Grid, for this generally we do use ArrayList of Employee Object( which had the properties like coloms in Employee table with same data types & each setter,getter for each property),

No i wanna transfore employee table data through ArrayList,but with out using list of any objects.

Answer (score 0):

List list = Arrays.asList(table);

Comment: actually i want to transfer all enployees data from Employee table to flex Data Grid, for this generally we do use ArrayList of Employee Object( which had the properties like coloms in Employee table with same data types & each setter,getter for each property),

No i wanna transfore employee table data through ArrayList,but with out using list of any objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a `JTable` you have to pass through the model to obtain the data you need. But it won't be so straightforward since the only method you have for sure is `getValueAt(int row, int col)` that is not efficient to retrieve the whole list of elements of the table.

Usually you don't use just a `DefaultTableModel` but a custom one that must has a way to keep track of the list of employees for sure..

In other case you will have to wrap all the column values for a row inside an object (also if you don't have any `MyBean` class object) or use a composite object, otherwise it would be just crazy.

Comment: actually i want to transfer all enployees data from Employee table to flex Data Grid, for this generally we do use ArrayList of Employee Object( which had the properties like coloms in Employee table with same data types & each setter,getter for each property),

No i wanna transfore employee table data through ArrayList,but with out using list of any objects.

Comment: So you are asking if in a full object oriented programming language in which everything is an object at the point that also your `main` method must be contained in an object you are allowed to use an `ArrayList` of "non-objects"? __No__, that's not possible.. I don't really see how you could avoid using objects, you could use an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s but they would be objects anyway..

Comment: the `ArrayList` itself is a parametrized class that must be attached to a specific type. So the real type of an `ArrayList` includes the type variable: `ArrayList<Employee>` or `ArrayList<String>`

Comment: i hare 2 result sets here, one is holding the column namee, one is holding rows of column,

now i want to form a arrayList with rows & colomns how can i do?